# SQL Server Enterprise Manager Download? (Or Windows 7 equivalent?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I maintain a couple of older sites running SQL Server 2000 and 2005. On my old XP  box I was using SQL Server Enterprise Manager to access them.

I'm now on a Windows 7 box. Is that product still available for download/install and will it run on Windows 7? I can't seem to find a download for that specific component.

Or is there an alternative for Windows 7? I tried install SQL Server 2008 Manager Express, but the fails halfway through on Windows 7. I do have XP running in Virtual Box so could get by with Enterprise Manager if I could figure out where to install it from.

Comment: in nutshell it's replace with "SQL Server Management Studio"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enterprise Manager only supports up to sql server 2000.  You can't use it to access sql server 2005.  Instead, you need Sql Server Management Studio.  You can download the express edition here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796

I'm running both management studio and windows 7 just fine.

As for enterprise manager, it was *never* available for download.  You had to install it from the media that came with sql server.  Similarly, if you want a non-express edition of management studio you need to install it when running setup for sql server.

Comment: I just slapped my forehead. 'doh! Thanks for the answer!